# EXCEL: Populate a value corresponding to common row on another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

There are three sheets:

1. The master sheet
2. The 2020 figures
3. The 2021 figures

The layout of the 2020 and 2021 sheets is like this:

[image: Sample cells] 
 Figure 1 showing codes in column A. In column B is a count of the total number of occurrences in that year using a simple COUNTA function.

My resuest is for a formula on the master sheet which currently looks like this:

[image]

Figure 2 showing the codes in column A. In column B is a count of the total number of occurences accross years, this is gained by adding the corresponding value in column D (the year 1 count) to the value in column F (the year 2 count).

Currently I have to manually enter the year 2 values to update them after working with the 2021 sheet. I would like a formula in F cells that finds the row specified by column A in the sheet specified by column E, and then take and show the B value from the 2021 sheet.

Does this make sense? How do I do this?

UPDATE:

I've now tried the following VLOOKUP formula but I'm getting an error and I can't tell why it won't work:

=VLOOKUP($A29,'2021'!$A2:$A60,2)

Comment: Your codes are different. On the master sheet, some have leading zeros while on the years' sheets, they don't.

Comment: Can there be any date of any year in the Date columns of Table 1?  If not, please fill in some representative data.